# Change the default Mouse Pointer Colour on boot in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8.1

How do I change the default (White to black) Mouse Pointer Colour on boot in windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour go to

- setting
- change pc settings
- ease of access
- mouse